# Poll SCM for a specific branch Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Github project with many branches.

```
Example

master
staging
feature-1
feature-2
```

I have a Jenkins job that has the "Poll SCM" option enabled with the following cronjob (10 7,9,11,13,15,17,19 * * 1-5)

However, this job will kick off when a change is made to master also.

I want a Jenkins job to only kick off if a commit to the staging branch.

Here is an output of the polling logs

```
Started on Nov 20, 2018 1:10:00 PM
no polling baseline in /var/jenkins_workspace/workspace/Staging-ALL-Deploy@libs/jenkins-pipeline-global-lib on 
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision efccc8e212470802d64537e0a5e710f9b5c063b6 (refs/remotes/origin/staging)
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git ls-remote -h http://git.company.com/org/repo.git # timeout=10
Found 56 remote heads on http://git.company.com/org/repo.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/staging is: efccc8e212470802d64537e0a5e710f9b5c063b6 - already built by 171
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision efccc8e212470802d64537e0a5e710f9b5c063b6 (refs/remotes/origin/staging)
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git ls-remote -h http://git.company.com/org/repo.git # timeout=10
Found 56 remote heads on http://git.company.com/org/repo.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: 865459e59ef5f91fddbd7453d9f2205560327c44
Done. Took 0.46 sec
Changes found
```

Is this possible?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set which branch you want to build with following way:

Configure -> Source Code Management tab -> Branch to Build -> Branch specifier

just write staging in this section. Then go to Build Triggers tab, select GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling.

Don't forget to add webhook `<YOUR-JENKINS-URL>/github-webhook/` to your Github project and select sending push events as json.

With this way, you can create a build whenever a push made to a specific branch. With pooling, it will pull the repository with given time intervals, which is way more costly.

Comment: What if you have two repos and you only want to build one of the branches in one of the repos? Current behavior seems to trigger for a push to either branch/repo.

Comment: I see an option under "Additional Behaviors"  called "Don't trigger a build on commit notifications" that looks like it will work.

Comment: Thank you @ElijahLynn. Additional Behaviors worked for me also.

Comment: @secil what would jenkinsfile look like